# How to drop support for IE, and prevent babel transpilation to ES5 in order to gain performance gain

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, webpack-4, babel-loader, react-app-rewired

Currently I am using default webpack config of Create React App for babel transpilation.
It seems that default babel-loader (in CRA config) uses "babel-preset-react-app". Now all I want is to prevent the transpilation of JS files to ES5 since I don't need to support Internet Explorer.
I'm hoping this will bring some gain in the build time.

Versions being used:

- Webpack 4
- Babel Loader 8
- react-app-rewired 2.1
- customize-cra 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `browserslist` configuration in your `package.json` to set the target browsers.

```
{
 ...
 "browserslist": {
     ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not IE 11"
   }
}
```

You can also generate build as per your environment

```
"browserslist": {
   "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not IE 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is also mentioned in the official [CRA doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/).

I'd suggest taking a look at [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) to customize the rules as per your exact requirements.